# Which is the best solution for shared database meeting these requirements?

Tags: database, authentication, user-interface, logging, users

#### Which solution would you recommend which has:

- a *relational* database with a user interface
- access for 20-50 users potentially *working in parallel*
- user authentication
- log of changes
- customizable forms, to input data in the database
- different access rights levels (read, read & write, admin)
- data hosted on my server
- very little to absolutely no "programming" to be implemented
- as low cost as possible :)

#### Some background:

I currently have a Microsoft Access database, with different forms to facilitate the user interface. I would like to now give access to this database to roughly 20 users - so I need to be able to track who updates what.

Ideally I would like to have a Web 2.0 look and feel, but this is optional.

So far, I have looked into:

- Microsoft ASP.NET; but this seems to me like a lot of programming will be needed
- Open-source CRM, like Joomla, Drupal, or SugarCRM; though it looks like an overkill for my objective, and I am not sure it will be easy to implement or manage
- [Zoho creator](http://creator.zoho.com/); this was the closest I have seen to my objective, but I understand the data is hosted on Zoho servers which *I do not want*

Any suggestion is most welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Programming frameworks like CakePHP, Django, and Rails all offer easy ways to scaffold an application. It requires more technological expertise than commercial database products, so you may need to hire a web/application developer to set things up for you.

That aside, I hear [FileMaker](http://www.filemaker.com/) is pretty decent. Not sure if it'll run on your hardware, but it may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

"Scafolding is usually some type of code generation where you point it at a database, and the technology creates basic CRUD (create, read, update, delete) screens."
found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235018/what-is-scaffolding-is-it-a-term-for-a-particular-platform).
Sounds interesting.

Is there an easy method to implement scaffolding?

Answer (score 1):

So far, **the closest I come to my objective** was:
- an mysql database, 
- an apache http web server,
- with phpmyadmin to administer the database, 
all packaged in xampp;

But *I am missing* at least *some front-end web forms*, for example based on php, to let users view and edit the database content.

There are some tools that generate php forms. I have tested for example [PHP Mysql Web Database Application Code generator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WEB-Design/Web-Design-related/ASPPHP-Web-Application-Builder.shtml). This software created for me with a click of a button a complete set of web forms, including menus, and forms to view and edit content. BUT... there were some bugs so I dropped it...

so I am still looking.

Right now, I am looking into phpmyedit for creating my web forms.
It is free, and seems to work so far. I have created some forms. But I am not satisfied yet with the forms and need to customize them.

Answer (score 0):

Dabo looks interesting:

http://dabodev.com/

It appears to be something like Visual FoxPro but in Python.